# Unable to Activate Google Cloud Account - Status Shows "Closed"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, billing

I recently set up a Google Cloud account and added a debit card to set up the billing account. However, after creating the account, I noticed that the status of the account is marked as 'Closed' and never showed up as 'Active' (as shown in the image below).

[image]

I also tried to create multiple billing accounts but it is not working.
I need to activate this account to link it to a project and generate an API key. How can I change the account status from "Closed" to "Activated"?

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Best contact billing support for GCP to have a better understanding and assistance with your issue. [1] Could be something account related that needs to be fixed.

[1]

https://cloud.google.com/support/billing?_ga=2.16820857.-11833560.1674832006